# How do I remove my Ubuntu One account?

Tags: ubuntu-one, delete, online-accounts

I don't want to cancel a subscription to a service. That is all that I could find with 'How to eliminate/deactivate Ubuntu One account?' Search.

On the Ubuntu One page there is a FAQ with the following: 'How do I downgrade or cancel my Ubuntu One account?'

Which only gives the following information: 'Do you want to either downgrade or cancel you Ubuntu One plan? Both the downgrade and cancel options are available in the Account area. https://one.ubuntu.com/account/ Under 'Services' > 'Your Storage'. Click on the grey "See Details" button next to all the subscription(s) you want to cancel and then click the "Cancel this subscription" button.'

In the TOS it says: '
Cancelling your account.
You may cancel your account at any time through the Ubuntu One website. You must cancel your service before it renews in order to avoid billing of the next period's fees to your credit card. You will not be charged at the next renewal date, but Canonical does not provide refunds for any previous billing periods or partial billing periods. We will not charge a fee for cancelling your account.'

Please tell me how to cancel an account. Not deactivate or suspend or disable services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't just want to stop the account, but delete all associated data? That will also remove your Ubuntu SSO, which means that accounts on sites you've logged into using those credentials (like possibly this one), will also become unavailable unless they have special features to re-associate accounts.

I don't think that's possible using the webui, so you should contact customer support: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Answer (score 1):

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+question/108472

> You can cancel your account by doing the following:
>
> 1. Open https://one.ubuntu.com/account/
> 2. Click on the "View details or make changes" link
> 3. Click the "Cancel this subscription" link
> 4. Click the "Cancel subscription" button

This may help

Comment: No, that's still just removing the subscription. my ubuntu one account hasn't been canceled.

Comment: Removing your subscription is 'canceling your Ubuntu One account'. Ubuntu One uses Single Sign On to authenticate. Your Single Sign On account is different from your Ubuntu One subscription. Once you cancel your subscription their is nothing more to cancel with Ubuntu One

Answer (score 0):

After cancelling your Ubuntu One account, you may also want to cancel your SSO (login.ubuntu.com) account.  Here's the link for instructions:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SSO/FAQs/Delete_SSO_Account